# AutoHotKey - Defining variable and printing it out

Tags: autohotkey, shortcut

Defining variable and printing it out

Hey guys!

I just found AHK, and I love it!

I'm currently writing a script, which allows me to select some different options from a dropdown, and then it will automatically enter the value from that dropdown in a specific field:

Now my problem is, that when I example choose "SPIRIT" - for some reason it enters these numbers:

"643232442221" and NOT the numbers it is supposed to: "6432324422"

It's like it's adding extra numbers to the field. Why is that???

```
#T::
Gui, Add, Text, x26 y177 w420 h30 , Vælg Handling Agent
Gui, Add, DropDownList, x26 y217 w420 h20 vCfs, WFS|Spirit
Gui, Show, x131 y91 h381 w481, New GUI Window

Submit:
Gui, Submit

varCfs = %cfs%
varConsol = %consol%
varMawb = %mawb%

if(varCfs = "WFS"){
   varCfs = 6402111562
} else if (varCfs = "SPIRIT"){
   varCfs = 6432324422
}

Gui, Hide

;After submit. If the console # is already opened in EDIe, make that window active
;if not, let's generate an error, saying that the user must lookup the console.
IfWinExist, Edit Consol %consol% 
{
    WinActivate ; use the window found above
     ;Arrival Info
     Click 697,76 
     Click 651,109
     Send {Ctrl Down}a{Ctrl Up}
     Sleep 200
     Send {Delete}
     Sleep 350
     Send %varCfs%      

     +F11::Send, %mawb% ;Shift+F11


} else {
    WinActivate, ediEnterprise
    MsgBox, 4, Find Consol #, Error!
    Gui, Destroy
    Gui, show
    Return ;Then stop! 
}



Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: What is `varMawb`? Is it ever "21"?

Comment: Yes, it's 217xxxxxxx

Comment: Try the answer from @vasili111. You can't declare a hotkey inside of `IfWinExist` like you tried to do with `+F11::`. I'm betting that after the `Send %varCfs%` you immediately get `Send, %mawb%`. To declare a conditional hotkey, user `#IfWinExist` (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce environment to test your code. But I made some corrections that maybe can help you. Try this code:

```
#T::
Gui, Add, Text, x26 y177 w420 h30 , Vælg Handling Agent
Gui, Add, DropDownList, x26 y217 w420 h20 vCfs, WFS|Spirit
Gui, Show, x131 y91 h381 w481, New GUI Window

Submit:
Gui, Submit

varCfs := cfs
varConsol := consol
varMawb := mawb

if(varCfs = "WFS"){
   varCfs := 6402111562
} else if (varCfs = "SPIRIT"){
   varCfs := 6432324422
}

Gui, Hide

;After submit. If the console # is already opened in EDIe, make that window active
;if not, let's generate an error, saying that the user must lookup the console.
IfWinExist, Edit Consol %consol% 
{
    WinActivate ; use the window found above
     ;Arrival Info
     Click 697,76 
     Click 651,109
     Send {Ctrl Down}a{Ctrl Up}
     Sleep 200
     Send {Delete}
     Sleep 350
     Send %varCfs%      




} else {
    WinActivate, ediEnterprise
    MsgBox, 4, Find Consol #, Error!
    Gui, Destroy
    Gui, show
    Return ;Then stop! 
}



Return

+F11::Send, %mawb% ;Shift+F11

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```